# react-native-svg undefined symbols dylib when compiling on iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, react-native-svg

I'm trying to compile a React Native app on iOS.

Many times I encounter an error related to the linker, which essentially says that `dylib` reports there are undefined symbols, which are related to some `pod` modules linked to the project.

In my case I'm having trouble with `react-native-svg`

To install the package and compile:

```
$ npm install --save react-native-svg
$ npx pod-install  # or cd ios && pod install && cd ..
$ npx react-native link react-native-svg
$ open ios/<project-name>.xcworkspace &
$ # then compile the react-native project in iOS
```

So:

- Package is installed
- Podfiles are installed
- Package is linked

Sometimes this happens when compiling for simulator (x86_64) and sometimes it happens when compiling for my device (arm64). It appears randomly, but nothing I do solves the problem.  Sometimes it works after a reboot, sometimes not. Sometimes it works after cleaning the build folder , sometimes not.  Sometimes it works after restarting Xcode, sometimes not. Sometimes it works after re-running `pod install` and re-linking works, sometimes not.  Nothing appears to work consistently.

Any insight would be appreciated.

The errors are as follows

```
Ld /Users/adonis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/pktwallet-cuihgpnujfgpvbcdatertduvqenu/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/RNSVG/RNSVG.framework/RNSVG normal (in target 'RNSVG' from project 'Pods')
    cd /Users/adonis/sandbox/my-projects/github/pktwallet-mobile/ios-tests/pktwallet/ios/Pods
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -target arm64-apple-ios9.0 -dynamiclib -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS15.2.sdk -L/Users/adonis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/pktwallet-cuihgpnujfgpvbcdatertduvqenu/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/RNSVG -F/Users/adonis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/pktwallet-cuihgpnujfgpvbcdatertduvqenu/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/RNSVG -F/Users/adonis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/pktwallet-cuihgpnujfgpvbcdatertduvqenu/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/DoubleConversion -F/Users/adonis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/pktwallet-cuihgpnujfgpvbcdatertduvqenu/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/FBReactNativeSpec -F/Users/adonis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/pktwallet-cuihgpnujfgpvbcdatertduvqenu/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/RCT-Folly -F/Users/adonis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/pktwallet-cuihgpnujfgpvbcdatertduvqenu/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/RCTTypeSafety -F/Users/adonis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/pktwallet-cuihgpnujfgpvbcdatertduvqenu/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/React-Core -F/Users/adonis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/pktwallet-cuihgpnujfgpvbcdatertduvqenu/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/React-RCTAnimation -F/Users/adonis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/pktwallet-cuihgpnujfgpvbcdatertduvqenu/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/React-RCTBlob -F/Users/adonis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/pktwallet-cuihgpnujfgpvbcdatertduvqenu/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/React-RCTImage -F/Users/adonis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/pktwallet-cuihgpnujfgpvbcdatertduvqenu/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/React-RCTLinking -F/Users/adonis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/pktwallet-cuihgpnujfgpvbcdatertduvqenu/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/React-RCTNetwork -F/Users/adonis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/pktwallet-cuihgpnujfgpvbcdatertduvqenu/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/React-RCTSettings -F/Users/adonis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/pktwallet-cuihgpnujfgpvbcdatertduvqenu/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/React-RCTText -F/Users/adonis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/pktwallet-cuihgpnujfgpvbcdatertduvqenu/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/React-RCTVibration -F/Users/adonis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/pktwallet-cuihgpnujfgpvbcdatertduvqenu/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/React-cxxreact -F/Users/adonis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/pktwallet-cuihgpnujfgpvbcdatertduvqenu/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/React-jsi -F/Users/adonis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/pktwallet-cuihgpnujfgpvbcdatertduvqenu/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/React-jsiexecutor -F/Users/adonis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/pktwallet-cuihgpnujfgpvbcdatertduvqenu/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/React-jsinspector -F/Users/adonis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/pktwallet-cuihgpnujfgpvbcdatertduvqenu/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/React-perflogger -F/Users/adonis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/pktwallet-cuihgpnujfgpvbcdatertduvqenu/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/ReactCommon -F/Users/adonis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/pktwallet-cuihgpnujfgpvbcdatertduvqenu/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Yoga -F/Users/adonis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/pktwallet-cuihgpnujfgpvbcdatertduvqenu/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/glog -filelist /Users/adonis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/pktwallet-cuihgpnujfgpvbcdatertduvqenu/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphoneos/RNSVG.build/Objects-normal/arm64/RNSVG.LinkFileList -install_name @rpath/RNSVG.framework/RNSVG -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @loader_path/Frameworks -dead_strip -Xlinker -object_path_lto -Xlinker /Users/adonis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/pktwallet-cuihgpnujfgpvbcdatertduvqenu/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphoneos/RNSVG.build/Objects-normal/arm64/RNSVG_lto.o -Xlinker -export_dynamic -Xlinker -no_deduplicate -fembed-bitcode-marker -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -framework Foundation -compatibility_version 1 -current_version 1 -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/adonis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/pktwallet-cuihgpnujfgpvbcdatertduvqenu/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphoneos/RNSVG.build/Objects-normal/arm64/RNSVG_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/adonis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/pktwallet-cuihgpnujfgpvbcdatertduvqenu/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/RNSVG/RNSVG.framework/RNSVG

ld: warning: dylib (/Users/adonis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/pktwallet-cuihgpnujfgpvbcdatertduvqenu/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Yoga/yoga.framework/yoga) was built for newer iOS version (10.0) than being linked (9.0)
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "__RCTNotImplementedException", referenced from:
      -[RNSVGPainter init] in RNSVGPainter.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_RCTFont", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in RNSVGGlyphContext.o
  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_RCTViewManager", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_RNSVGDefsManager in RNSVGDefsManager.o
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_RNSVGNodeManager in RNSVGNodeManager.o
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_RNSVGSvgViewManager in RNSVGSvgViewManager.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_RCTViewManager", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_RNSVGDefsManager in RNSVGDefsManager.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_RNSVGNodeManager in RNSVGNodeManager.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_RNSVGSvgViewManager in RNSVGSvgViewManager.o
  "_RCTConvertEnumValue", referenced from:
      +[RCTConvert(RNSVG) RNSVGCGFCRule:] in RCTConvert+RNSVG.o
      +[RCTConvert(RNSVG) RNSVGVBMOS:] in RCTConvert+RNSVG.o
      +[RCTConvert(RNSVG) RNSVGUnits:] in RCTConvert+RNSVG.o
  "__RCTLogNativeInternal", referenced from:
      +[RCTConvert(RNSVG) RNSVGBrush:] in RCTConvert+RNSVG.o
      +[RCTConvert(RNSVG) RNSVGCGRect:offset:] in RCTConvert+RNSVG.o
      +[RCTConvert(RNSVG) RNSVGCGColor:offset:] in RCTConvert+RNSVG.o
      -[RNSVGNode svgView] in RNSVGNode.o
      +[RNSVGNodeManager CATransform3DFromMatrix:] in RNSVGNodeManager.o
      +[RNSVGNodeManager CATransform3D:] in RNSVGNodeManager.o
      -[RNSVGPainter paintLinearGradient:bounds:] in RNSVGPainter.o
      ...
  "_RCTExecuteOnUIManagerQueue", referenced from:
      ___58-[RNSVGSvgViewManager toDataURL:options:callback:attempt:]_block_invoke in RNSVGSvgViewManager.o
  "_RCTRegisterModule", referenced from:
      +[RNSVGCircleManager load] in RNSVGCircleManager.o
      +[RNSVGClipPathManager load] in RNSVGClipPathManager.o
      +[RNSVGDefsManager load] in RNSVGDefsManager.o
      +[RNSVGEllipseManager load] in RNSVGEllipseManager.o
      +[RNSVGForeignObjectManager load] in RNSVGForeignObjectManager.o
      +[RNSVGGroupManager load] in RNSVGGroupManager.o
      +[RNSVGImageManager load] in RNSVGImageManager.o
      ...
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_RCTConvert", referenced from:
      __OBJC_$_CATEGORY_RCTConvert_$_RNSVG in RCTConvert+RNSVG.o
      objc-class-ref in RNSVGForeignObjectManager.o
      objc-class-ref in RNSVGImage.o
      objc-class-ref in RNSVGImageManager.o
      objc-class-ref in RNSVGMaskManager.o
      objc-class-ref in RNSVGNodeManager.o
      objc-class-ref in RNSVGPainter.o
      ...
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Answer (score 1):

I was with the exact same error here after added `use_frameworks!` in my Podfile, I suggest you reinstall to the newest version of this package, only this resolved for me.

execute this commands if you are using RN >= 0.60:

```
$ yarn remove react-native-svg

$ react-native unlink react-native-svg

$ yarn add react-native-svg

$ cd ios && pod install
```

Answer (score 0):

It *seems* like the solution was to go to my Pods and to upgrade the **Deployment Target version**.